# Urgent !!! Formulae unable to run

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to add the formula in the workflow mentioned below:

```
AND( ISCHANGED (Account.Name),OR( ( Account.Type  =  'Client')))
```

But it shows this error:

> The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Account.Name field

Basically I trying to do here is when I change the `Account Name` field on `Contact` and `Account Type` field on account is "Client", the `Contact Owner` should get an email alert.

[image]

The account name is a lookup value here. Can you suggest me a correct formula?

Comment: Kunal: Why would you use ">" operater for a lookup field ?? And try just using "Account" not "Account.Name". Use "<>" operator

Comment: "Urgent!!!" is not community etiquette - please refrain from exhortations

Answer (score 0):

the reason this isn't working on a contact workflow is because the changed fields live on another object - the account.

the workaround would be to have a text field, that would be hidden, on the contact record for the account name that would be updated by workflow every time the record is edited.  **mark this field update to trigger other workflow rules.**  then you can create the workflow you're trying to make with the ISCHANGED() and PRIORVALUE() functions on a field on the contact record.